# Google Chrome failed to print preview issue (Out of memory/ page not responding)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, printing

[image]Hi please help me out for this issue.

If I print less then 100 page it is working fine, but when I try to print 100/100+ pages it is throwing print preview issue.

All the 100 pages have the one image in each. Image size is around 70KB or more.

If I print 50/60 it will work fine.

Please do help me with this issue.

Comment: It looks like the print previewer needs to render the whole document in Chrome [see semi-related bug report](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8007).  So it could, in fact, be running out of memory if it's a complex document.

Comment: Some cases it will show out of memory and some cases it will show only Print preview failed.

Comment: I am converting pdf as image and displaying in canvas. will it affect, is there any other way I can bind pdf in html

Comment: I am converting pdf to image using canvas, that is causing image data issue, I guess. is there any way we can convert pdf to image with lesser in size

Comment: It all depends on what pdf library you are using and whether it supports that kind of thing.

Comment: if I try to [print 50 60 pages are working fine. But 100 or more then 100 causing issue.

Comment: I also have this issue even on for web pages even if there's only very few pages. I didn't have this issue with older versions of Chrome.